# Requests with AJAX in a portlet (Liferay)

Tags: ajax, post, get, liferay

I have an issue with my portlet and I don't know exactly how to solve it.
My portlet adds or retrieves info from liferay's DB by inserting a name in 2 text fields.
After pressing the submit button, I see the response from the server, a JSON response like this:

```
{"id":301,"name":"Pepo"}
```

If a user correctly inserted or if the search throws a good result. I have to go back in the browser to see the portal again.

How can I use AJAX to pass the following URL dynamically from the portlet to the server without refreshing the page afterwards?

> http://localhost:8080/c/portal/json_service?serviceClassName=com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=findByName&servletContextName=TrabajadorPlugin-portlet&serviceParameters=[param1]&param1=**NameInsertedByUser**

Now I'm using the `<form>` tag like this:

```
<%
//Shows "New Employee" in the text field when portlet is rendered, or gets the user input and pass it as a param to the URL
PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences(); 
String employee = (String)prefs.getValue("name", "New Employee");  
%>

<form id="postForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/c/portal/json_service">
    <input name="serviceClassName" type="hidden" value="com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil" />
    <input name="serviceMethodName" type="hidden" value="create" />
    <input name="servletContextName" type="hidden" value="TrabajadorPlugin-portlet" />
    <input name="serviceParameters" type="hidden" value="[param]" />
    <input name="param" type="text" value="<%=employee%>" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

I understand how AJAX works, but I need some help to create my function in order to achieve the URL to be correctly sent to the server for both `GET` and `POST` requests. This is my first try with AJAX.

Thank you very much, hope somebody understands my problem and could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I see no point at all to use JSON services here. Just write ordinary portlet with MVC Controller, and in controller write action handling for corresponding actions (storing data, searching etc).

In controller you can directly call static methods like create or findByName from java class com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil (or TrabajadorLocalServiceUtil) - that's how people usually do it.

If for some reason you really must use JSON, you should of course do these actions with AJAX calls - and render results using JavaScript.

Updating after question update:

1. The easiest and most correct way to send AJAX requests in Liferay would be to use AlloyUI JS framework that's a part of Liferay. You can read more on how to send AJAX requests with it here: http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/4733559
2. In order to accomplish your goal I'd suggest implementing processAction(ActionRequest actRequest, ActionResponse actResponse) method in your controller/portlet. 
   In order to actually send data to it you'll have to have actionURL, which you can create using for example portlet:actionURL tag:

   `<portlet:actionURL />` or with Java code `PortletURL actionUrl = portletResponse.createActionURL();`
3. Then just submit your form using POST to this URL, and in actionRequest you'll have your parameters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that yes, I'm sending and receiving the GET and POST request in JSON like that: {"id":301,"name":"Pepo"}
So yes, I need to use AJAX but I don't know how. MY URL is like:
http://localhost:8080/c/portal/json_service?serviceClassName=com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=findByName&servletContextName=TrabajadorPlugin-portlet&serviceParameters=[param1]&param1=Pepo

Comment: Where Param1 is inserted by the user in a text field. I just need to add it at the end of the URL and send it with AJAX so that you don't see that blank page and you don't need to refresh the browser manually to come back to the portal. Do you have any suggestion to do that? THanks a lot, this is my first time with AJAX and I'm a little bit lost.